# How does one deal with obtaining precise solutions with the command FindRoot in Mathematica?

Tags: interpolation, wolfram-mathematica

Currently, I am trying to use common tangent construction, a thermodynamic construct in Materials Science to find phase coexistence, using FindRoot along with Interpolation. The code is given below.

```
    data1 = Import["F-vs-Phi-5.0.dat", Method -> "Spline"]
    f = Interpolation[data1, Method -> "Spline"];
    sol = FindRoot[{y1 == f[x1], y2 == f[x2], f'[x1] == f'[x2], 
    f'[x1] == (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)}, {x1, 100}, {x2, 
    400}, {y1, -0.032272}, {y2, -0.133145}]
    line[x_] = y1 + f'[x1] (x - x1) /. sol;
    Plot[{f[x], line[x]}, {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. sol]}]
```

and it has been lifted from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25892/common-tangent-to-a-curve. The link to the data set is https://pastebin.com/D2iQk1yS.

The problem here is that the above code gives different answers depending on the initial guess. For example, the guess in the code above gives x1 -> 100.057, x2 -> 399.471, y1 -> -0.0322865, y2 -> -0.132949. And when I change the initial guess for x1 to 50, it gives x1 -> 49.9562, x2 -> 450.048, y1 -> -0.0161457, y2 -> -0.149849. Now the slope of the data set is plotted below. It clearly suggests that the solution exists to the data set. But what is worrisome is the code malfunctioning here.
[Slope of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgWzS.png)

Comment: I have sorted out the issue with the search range. However, a different problem has come up and I have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple solutions to the problem and where you start determines the first solution that it finds? Are the solutions it is finding all correct? Or are the alternative solutions substantially incorrect? You might be able to try to use something like `Reduce` which should return every solution,, but with `Interpolation` and `MachinePrecision` numbers `Reduce might have problems providing what you want. If it worked and it did return 3 or 300 solutions then you might know.